# How to hide ng-message with timeout?

Tags: angularjs

I dont want ng-message to keep showing until user enters valid input. So I want to hide the ng-message say after 5 seconds on showing.

I saw the class toggle from ng-active to ng-inactive.

Now how can i manually set ng-message to inactive or hide it after some seconds?

Comment: I know how to use timeout. Now how will you detect whether ng-message is shown?

Comment: Here is a full exemple of something similar i did for an other answer. http://plnkr.co/edit/Fmhs6Dj8ozq1v1oTJGHG?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@muller` answer is solved your problem. but it's a temporary solution only.  Because if you used more `ng-message` you need to manage all of them.

But my options is you may go to **[AngularJS-Toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster)**. AngularJS Toaster is a customized version of "toastr" non-blocking notification javascript library.

I hope You can see the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HKTC1a?p=preview) for more clarifications .

And son't worry about the integrations. We don't need long time to integrate this. you just need to download the files from the link which I bring above (js,css) and drag the files to your main screen . That's all.

Comment: I'll have a look at the toaster.

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.showMessage = false;
}, 5000)
```

edit: to know if the message is shown you can watch the value of the condition (error) I assume (e.g. if the condition is required,  watch the error object of your [input field].$error.required..)

Comment: This is a big application. Also I am generating the messages dynamically. At a time user will be filling lot of inputs and multiple errors will be shown. How can i solve this with a single flag.